# In SSRS, how to make columns align properly after few of the columns are made to disappear based on condition

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a report in SSRS 2012 that has few column which need to be arranged in such a way as shown in image. ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxt93.png). I have columns PatientID,ID,DeviceA, DeviceB,DeviceC, Total.
Under DeviceA - I have subcolumns CountR,CountP,CountN, Also similarly I have same subcolumns under DeviceB, DeviceC and Total. Now I want Device A, Device B, Device C to appear or disappear based on whether there are values in these subcolumns or if they are null. Now once I make the columns disappear, the adjacent column should align beside The column before the column which disappeared. Ex if Device C disappears, I need total column with all its subcolumns to align next to Device B. How do I do this? Right now if a column DeviceC disappears, there is a gap between Device B and Total . How do I prevent the gap?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a table then this is probably the wrong way to design this report. You should use a matrix (its a table/tablix with both row and column groups).

You might have to redesign the dataset output too but without more info it's hard to tell, but basically each cell will be on it's own row something like

```
PatientID Device CountType Amount
1234      A      countR    10
1234      B      countN    11
1234      C      countP    12
5678      A      countR    11
5678      B      countN    11
```

etc...

Your matrix will then need to be grouped by patientid in the Row groups and then by both device and counttype in the column groups (these will be separate groups). There is no need to hide columns as they will not be displayed if there is no data anyway.